# Как динамически изменить ширину виджета комментариев Вконтакте?

Tags: виджет, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как динамически изменить ширину виджета комментариев Вконтакте?

Comment: Опишите поподробней задачу. Грубо говоря, открыта страничка в браузере, Вы хотите добавить в браузер кнопку, по нажатию на которую все блоки комментариев увеличатся? Или Вы придумали способ внедрения скрипта во ВК и хотите это сделать оттуда?

Comment: Нет, все просто. Есть виджет комментариев на своем сайте. встроен через JS - и соответственно IFrame. Вот как в Iframe изменить параметры длины. а то при растягивании страницы все сджимается/расжимается, а ширина виджета остается неизменной

Comment: А там разве не параметрами и настройками приложения задаётся?

Comment: в том то и дело, что параметрами задается, просто когда меняешь размер страницы - эти параметры остаются прежними. и виджет вылезает за пределы окна

Answer (score 2):

У меня так :

```
<div width="100%" id="vk_groups"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    var size_man = jQuery('#vk_groups').width();
VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups", {mode: 0, height: "400",width: size_man, color1: 'FFFFFF', color2: '2B587A', color3: '5B7FA6'}, XXXXXXX); 
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я просто убрал параметр width из скрипта

`VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {limit: 20, attach: "*"});`

и все - виджет стал на 100% по ширине.

Answer (score 0):

Покопавшись в документации, не нашёл конкретного ответа, поэтому придумал данное решение. Может быть не самое лучшее, но с задачей справляется.

```
HTML:
<div id="vk_comments"></div>

JS:
var globalTimer = null;

window.onload = function() { 
    // при загрузке устанавливаем параметры по умолчанию
    VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {limit: 5, width: "520", attach: "*"});
};

window.onresize = function () {
    //при изменении размеров окна сначала очищаем наш блок с комментариями
    document.getElementById('vk_comments').innerHTML = '';

    // вызываем через таймер функцию отрисовки (для правки бага с двойной отрисовкой)        
    clearTimeout(globalTimer);
    globalTimer = setTimeout(doneResize, 300);
};

function doneResize(){
    //заново инициализируем комментарии с новой шириной
    //тут можно придумать зависимость ширины комментариев от ширины чего-нибудь и вставлять вместо 320 любую другую велечину
    VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {limit: 5, width: "320", attach: "*"});
}
```

Надеюсь суть ясна. Буду рад, если кто расскажет способ получше.

Answer (score 0):

Наверняка кому-то мой ответ поможет. Сделал очень просто

```
VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {limit: 5, width: "100%", attach: "*"});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {limit: 5, width: "", attach: "*"});
```

Вот так очень качественный резиновый стиль

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать класс (.container) с динамически изменяемой шириной блока, равный ширине страничного документа. При изменении размера окна, виджет перегружается с новым размером по ширине контейнера.

```html
<div width="100%" id="vk_comments"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    size_man = $('.container').width();
 VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_groups", {mode: 3, height: "400",width: size_man, color1: 'FFFFFF', color2: '2B587A', color3: '5B7FA6'}, xxxxxxxxx); 
 var globalTimer = null;
 window.onresize = function () {
    //при изменении размеров окна сначала очищаем наш блок с комментариями
    document.getElementById('vk_groups').innerHTML = '';

    // вызываем через таймер функцию отрисовки (для правки бага с двойной отрисовкой)        
    clearTimeout(globalTimer);
    globalTimer = setTimeout(doneResize, 300);
    // получаю ширину из резинового класса уже после того как размер изменился, DOM сформирована заново
    size_man = $('.container').width();
};
function doneResize(){
    //заново инициализируем комментарии с новой шириной
    VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {mode: 3, height: "400",width: size_man, color1: 'FFFFFF', color2: '2B587A', color3: '5B7FA6'}, xxxxxxxxx);
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на SO. Извиините за замечание, но в данной теме ожидается конкретный ответ на вопрос заданный ТС.  "но с учётом своих нужд" - вы можете сами задать вопрос и сами на него ответить с учётом ваших нужд. Так как этот ресурс не работает как привычные форумы, настоятельно рекомендую ознакомится с его механикой в справке или пройти тур,  который вам был предложен при  регистрации.